# Value does not fall within the expected range is thrown while changing orientation in a windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am encountering the following exception when I attempt to change orientation on a windows phone 8 page containing a longlistselector control with more than one item in the list (it works fine with only one item in the list) and can't seem to locate a viable work-around/solution (by finding a viable work-around, I don't want to turn off the ability to change orientation).  The exception is thrown before OnOrientationChanged event fires, in fact the OnOrientationChanged event never fires.

The following exception is thrown twice (I assumed it was once for each item in the longlistselector, but when I have more than two items in the longlistselector it continues to only throw the exception twice):

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
 at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
 at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_UpdateLayout(UIElement element)
 at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.UpdateOrientationTransform()
 at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.System.Windows.Controls.IFrame.InternalOnBeginLayoutChanged(Object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs args)
 at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Controls.Frame.FireEventHandler[T](EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender, T args)
 at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.set_LayoutOrientation(PageOrientation value)
 at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
 at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.UIOrientationChange(Orientations orientation)
 at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnUIOrientationChange(Orientations orientation)
 at System.Windows.Navigation.Journal.OrientationChanged(Orientations orientation)
 at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnOrientationChanged(Int32 orientation)}
```

I've created a simple project that I will gladly email to whomever would like to review it to specifically what I am seeing...it does nothing more than open the main page and load a few items (checkboxes) into a longlistselector control.  To duplicate the issue, simply run the app with 2 or more items in the longlistselector and attempt to change orientation.

The following is a copy of the MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- LOCALIZATION NOTE:
            To localize the displayed strings copy their values to appropriately named
            keys in the app's neutral language resource file (AppResources.resx) then
            replace the hard-coded text value between the attributes' quotation marks
            with the binding clause whose path points to that string name.

            For example:

                Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"

            This binding points to the template's string resource named "ApplicationTitle".

            Adding supported languages in the Project Properties tab will create a
            new resx file per language that can carry the translated values of your
            UI strings. The binding in these examples will cause the value of the
            attributes to be drawn from the .resx file that matches the
            CurrentUICulture of the app at run time.
         -->

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LongList"/>

        </Grid>

        <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
            aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
            account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
            if the System Tray is hidden.

            Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
        <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The following is a copy of the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp2.Resources;

namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private void LoadPageWithData()
        {
            LongList.ItemsSource = null;

            System.Collections.Generic.List<CheckBox> Items = new List<CheckBox>();

            //fetch planes from the data base and load onto the wnd
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                CheckBox _CB = new CheckBox();
                _CB.Content = "Plane" + j;
                _CB.Tag = j;
                Items.Add(_CB);
            }

            LongList.ItemsSource = Items;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            LoadPageWithData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of emailing us a project, can you amend your post with the smallest code snippet that compiles and reproduces the error?

Comment: Hi AndyG, Thanks for response.  I have added the code snippets you requested.  The snippet as it stands will reproduce the issue.  To make it work without producing the issue, change line 32 from "j < 2" to "j < 1".

Comment: I don't claim to know anything about windows phone development or C#, but wouldn't `Items` go out of scope after `LoadPageWithData` is called? Can you add it instead as a member variable to your class?

Comment: Hi AndyG, The reference lives on in memory as part of the LongListSelector.  The GC will see a reference in use and should not remove the reference from memory...should not being the operative phrase, so I double checked.  Moving the Items to an object level variable/member didn't change the outcome.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Excited to find the question, as I have the same issue.  Bummer not to see an answer.  Wondering if the OP ever found a workaround?